# How many AR movies are in the demo?

Tags: bravely-default-demo

How many AR movies are in the *Bravely Default* demo? So far I can only play one of them the pendant movie from the [black and white fairy card](http://bravelydefault.nintendo.com/demo/#ar-cards). Do I need to progress to unlock any of them, or am I just not positioning the camera right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same for me. I can only get one you're talking about. I don't know if it's the quality of the cards i printed out or it's because there's only one video. From [this GameFAQs thread](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/643004-bravely-default-flying-fairy/67874985) about the European demo, it seems like that's the only one. 
Can't wait for the full game though!

Comment: The full game is supposed to have at least a dozen or so AR cards.